# Piecewise convexity and global convexity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $\left[0,1\right]$.
Consider $z\in\left(0,1\right)$ and suppose that $f$ is differentiable
and convex on $\left[0,z\right]$ and $\left[z,1\right]$. If $f'$
(i.e., $\frac{df}{dx}$) is continuous at $z$, then $f$ is convex
on $\left[0,1\right]$. - Is this proposition true? While I could not create a counter-example, I am finding it difficult to generate a clean proof as well.

Comment: OK, I got your answers, and thank all of you for that. However, I would like to add something more to this question. To what extent, can I relax continuity of $f'$, and still have global convexity? Following your lines of proof, it seems to me that as long as the left-side derivative ($f'_{-}$) at $z$, which is well defined, is less than the right-side derivative ($f'_{+}$) at $z$, which is well defined as well, global convexity prevails. I do not need continuity of $f'$ precisely - Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A differentiable function $f$ is convex on an interval $(a,b)$ if and only if its derivative $f'$ is increasing.

Therefore, your assumptions imply that $f'$ is increasing on $(0,z)$ and on $(z,1)$. Now your assumption that $f'$ is continuous immediately gives you that $f'$ is increasing on $(0,1)$ and therefore convex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I relax continuity of $f'$ at $z$, and just assume that the left-side derivative of $f$ at $z$ is less than the right-side derivative of $f$ at $z$, global convexity will still hold - is it right? In fact, I was wondering that is an "if and only if" condition to maintain global convexity.

Comment: Yes, you are right it generalizes in the way you suggest it. But note that this does not follow from the proof I gave because the criterion I used needs that $f$ is differentiable in the whole interval. If you weaken this assumption you will have to proof it in a different way. I think it will boil down to using the definition of convexity and show it explicitly like one would show the theorem I used in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A differentiable function is convex in an interval $I$ if and only if $f'$ is increasing in $I$. Now we have that
$$f'(x)\leq f'(z)\leq f'(y)$$
for any $0\leq x<z<y\leq 1$. Can you take it from here and show that the proposition is true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's true. $f$ is convex iff $f'$ is monotonically non-decreasing, but it works on $[0, z)$ and $(z, 1]$. But $f'$ is continuous at $z$ so it can't be less than 0 otherwise there would be a neighborhood where it is negative and thus not convex.